# ProgrammingError Thread error in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a two simple tables in a sqlite db.

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey, \
    create_engine, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relationship, sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///dir_graph.sqlite', echo=True)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()

class NodeType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nodetype'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20), unique=True)
    nodes = relationship('Node', backref='nodetype')

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def __repr__(self):
    return "Nodetype: %s" % self.name


class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20), unique=True)
    type_id = Column(Integer,
                 ForeignKey('nodetype.id'))


    def __init__(self, _name, _type_id):
        self.name = _name
        self.type_id = _type_id

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

After the run I interact with the interpreter. e.g. n1= Node('Node1',1) to learn about sqlalchemy. After I did a session.commit() and try another statement e.g. n2 = Node('n2',1) I get this error: 
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 3932 and this is thread id 5740 None None.

How can I continue a session after I did a commit ?
tnx

Comment: the error is a SQLite driver error and it's what it says, which is that you can't use a connection in two different threads - is there more to the story here, how exactly are you running the Session here ?  is there something with threading going on ?

Comment: Nothing intentional with threading. I run this code in Spyder. A run setting is to interact with the interpreter after the run. That is what I do. It looks like the commit() closes the connection and I have the reinitialise then. I Haven't found the excat tip in the SQLalchemy docs.

Comment: try running in the default Python interpreter or as a single script.  Never heard of "Spyder" but it's likely doing something weird with threads.

Comment: Hi @zzzeek, I think this case is happening a lot. Especially for application that intensively use TwistedThread defer mechanism. I have trying to solve this case all this day long. Any suggestion how can I safely use sqlalchemy inside of twisted defer thread?

Comment: never worked with twisted before but you need to ensure that a particular SQLAlchemy Session remains pegged to a single series of operations, and isn't shared to other series of operations that are doing different things.  A "Thread local" session may or may not be appropriate with twisted's thread pool.  I've no doubt this issue happens a lot when people try to use normal libraries with twisted as mixing twisted with threaded code necessarily requires a significant degree of familiarity with concurrency.

Answer (score 14):

SQLite by default prohibits the usage of a single connection in more than one thread.
just add `connect_args={'check_same_thread': False}` parameter to your `engine` variable like

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///dir_graph.sqlite', connect_args={'check_same_thread': False}, echo=True)
```

According to [`sqlite3.connect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect):

> By default, `check_same_thread` is `True` and only the creating thread may
>   use the connection. If set `False`, the returned connection may be
>   shared across multiple threads. **When using multiple threads with the
>   same connection writing operations should be serialized by the user to
>   avoid data corruption.**